# Upgrading weak-convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ to strong-convergence in compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $s,s'\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $s'<s$. Consider $u=u(t,x)\in C(\mathbb{R},H^s(\mathbb{R}))$ and suppose that, as $t$ goes to infinity, we have the following weak convergence: $$
u(t,\cdot)\rightharpoonup u^*(x) \quad \hbox{in} \quad H^{s'}(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $s'<s$ and "$\rightharpoonup$" denotes the weak convergence in $H^{s'}$. If we additionally assume that $u(t,\cdot)$ is uniformly bounded in $H^s$, say $$
u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},H^s(\mathbb{R})),
$$
does this imply that $u(t,\cdot)$ **strongly** converge to $u^*$ in $H^{s'}(K)$ for any $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ compact? Moreover, if we additionally assume that $u^*$ belongs to $H^s$ (recall that $s'<s$), does the previous hypotheses (weak convergence in $H^{s'}(\mathbb{R})$ and uniform boundedness in $H^s(\mathbb{R})$) imply **strong** convergence in $H^{r}(K)$ for all $s'\leq r<s$ and all $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ compact? In other words, if we have a function is converging in a very weak topology, but this function is also uniformly bounded in a **stronger** topology, does that implies that the function is locally-strongly converging in the topologies "in between" them (whenever "in between" has sense, like in this case)?

Comment: Yes, this follows by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem applied to your function multiplied by a smooth compactly supported cutoff function with valued $1$ in $K$.